# azure b2c forgotpassword redirect url having hash symbol

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, forgot-password

I have an angular app which shows the "sign in" link along with "forgot password". When I click the "forgot password", the following screen shows up with custom page. The problem is when I click "cancel" button , it redirect back to "localhost:4200/" but the problem is it has hash tag after the domain name '#' along with error_description. Ideally it should be '?' to get the querystring. What setting am I doing incorrectly that there is always a hash '#' after domain name.
Example:

http://localhost:4200/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90091%3a+The+user+has+cancelled+entering+self-asserted+information.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+c2c881df-d7d1-4b9e-b645-9c6e030e064e%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2020-02-20+16%3a21%3a33Z%0d%0a

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

In the initial authentication request, set the response_mode to query. You will get all responses back as part of the query parameter.

Comment: perfect!! Thank you!